# TestCafe - User Profile and Log In

Tags: google-chrome, e2e-testing, testcafe, user-roles, browser-automation

I have a scenario where I need to use the current user chrome profile. I expected that I don't need to log in to web app. I thought TestCafe would use stored credentials. But all tests are redirected to login page.
I launch testcafe tests with flag chrome:userProfile.

How could I run tests and use stored credentials in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe uses its own [Roles mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) to authenticate users. The login steps are executed only once during the first Role usage. Next time TestCafe restores the logged in user automatically.